# Программное создание БД (файл)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что имеем: Python 3.5

Что нужно:

Создать новую базу данных прямо в коде Python, уточняю именно НОВУЮ, с созданием файла собственно самой БД в той же папке, что и скрипт Python.

Так же в последствии нужно подключиться к ней, в зависимости от выбранного действия и выполнять определённые запросы, такие как "Создание таблицы", "Выбор адреса директории" (что то вроде `SELECT adress FROM journal WHERE titleOfPost = "Название поста"`), а так же собственно добавление адреса в поле `adress`.

Comment: google://python+sqlite3 , а потом сообщите, что именно не получилось сделать

Comment: Разбейте ваше задание на несколько подзадач и задайте более специфичный вопрос, если не ясно как выполнить какой-то шаг. В чём у вас конкретно затруднения? 1- знаете ли как найти путь к скрипту Питона, который исполняется? 2- знаете ли как создать базу данных по заданному пути? Например, знаете ли вы как создать sqlite3 базу данных в текущей директории?

Comment: Напишите, какую СУБД используете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны подключиться к дефолтной базе данных (например, для PostgreSQL это `postgres`) и выполнить запрос на создание новой БД.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='pass'")

dbname = "your_db_name"

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + dbname)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

А дальше всё как обычно: подключаетесь к вновь созданной БД и выполняете нужные вам запросы.

Comment: Не похоже, что файл собственно самой БД создаётся в той же папке, что и скрипт

Comment: @andreymal, PostgreSQL организует единую файловую структуру, в которой отдельные файлы не соответствуют непосредственно таблицам или другим объектам базы данных. Все данные хранятся в директории, путь к которой задаётся переменной `data_directory` в файле настроек сервера БД, для ОС Debian (Jessie) и PostgreSQL (версия 9.4) это `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Я-то в курсе, но задаче это всё равно не соответствует

Comment: @andreymal, я только общую концепцию описал, т.к. автор не указал необходимую ему СУБД.

Comment: Даже «общие концепции» у разных СУБД совершенно разные, такие дела